What does this inline-assembly code snippet in Valgrind mean?
What does this mean in Valgrind's VALGRIND_DO_CLIENT_REQUEST_EXPR?
__asm__ volatile (
  __SPECIAL_INSTRUCTION_PREAMBLE
  /* %RDX = client_request ( %RAX ) */        
  "xchgq %rbx, %rbx"
  : "=d" (_zzq_result)
  : "a" (&_zzq_args[0]), "0" (_zzq_default)
  : "cc", "memory"
)

Where __SPECIAL_INSTRUCTION_PREAMBLE is defined as:
#define __SPECIAL_INSTRUCTION_PREAMBLE    \
  "rolq $3,  %%rdi ; rolq $13, %%rdi\n\t" \
  "rolq $61, %%rdi ; rolq $51, %%rdi\n\t"

Seems like some black magic.

Please [edit] your question and add details and links to show where exactly you found this. I did not find this code but only other similar macro definitions that include a macro __SPECIAL_INSTRUCTION_PREAMBLE. The code in the question might be part of a specific version of valgrind while I might have checked a different version. see also https://docs.open-mpi.org/en/v5.0.2/app-debug/memchecker.html#application-performance-impacts-using-memchecker

@PaulFloyd: Bodo’s comment does not indicate they expected the macro to be defined by Open MPI. It says “see also” an Open MPI page, and that is just because the Open MPI page happens to contain some relevant information, because it is discussing the macro that is asked about here.

I doubt it. "Couldn't find" probably means "googled for __SPECIAL_INSTRUCTION_PREAMBLE and clicked on the first answer".  Looking for the name of the macro rather than its contents would have given better answers.

@PaulFloyd: The comment indicates its author checked a specific version of Valgrind. Your conjectures are not supported by the evidence and writing “The mind boggles” is inappropriate ad hominem.

OP initially exapanded one macro to make it simpler. Maybe @Bodo was confused by that.

@PaulFloyd In the first version of the question, the macro was manually expanded. That's why I did not find the code snippet in the Valgrind source and commented that I only found versions of the code that do use a macro __SPECIAL_INSTRUCTION_PREAMBLE. Based on this I wrongly assumed that the code snippet might be from adifferent version of Valgrind. Now the question shows the original code snippets from valgrind.h. Omitting the macro removed the information conveyed in its name "special instruction preamble".

Fair enough. Initial comment deleted. For info the macros are defined in valgrind.h. The amd64 asm last changed in 2006.

Also note that fairly often projects will just copy and paste these macros from valgrind.h. Most of Valgrind is GPLV2+, but the headers are explicitly under a BSD-like license to allow such copying and pasting.

There is no way for a 'client' executable to interact with the Valgrind host directly. The client and host have separate memory spaces. Unlike tools such as Purify and the Sanitizers Valgrind can't provide any C functions for clients to be able to introspect any information from the Valgrind host.
The client request mechanism uses a short asm preamble as a marker for the Valgrind host. This is a sequence of instructions that has no side effects and is also a sequence that no compiler will ever emit. It would be a big problem if ever compilers generated code that Valgrind incorrrectly saw as a client request. The amd64 example that you gave uses 4 left rotates of RDI with a total of 128 bits, leaving it unchanged. That's followed by an exchange of RBX with itself. Other CPU architectures use similar 'no-op' sequences to signal client requests.
Since these instructions do nothing they can be compiled into release builds with only a very small size and runtime overhead.
Here is the comment in the Valgrind source that explains these special instructions (in VEX/priv/guest_amd64_toIR.c - in Valgrind we use 'guest' and 'client' interchangeably).

/* "Special" instructions.

   This instruction decoder can decode three special instructions
   which mean nothing natively (are no-ops as far as regs/mem are
   concerned) but have meaning for supporting Valgrind.  A special
   instruction is flagged by the 16-byte preamble 48C1C703 48C1C70D
   48C1C73D 48C1C733 (in the standard interpretation, that means: rolq
   $3, %rdi; rolq $13, %rdi; rolq $61, %rdi; rolq $51, %rdi).
   Following that, one of the following 3 are allowed (standard
   interpretation in parentheses):

      4887DB (xchgq %rbx,%rbx)   %RDX = client_request ( %RAX )
      4887C9 (xchgq %rcx,%rcx)   %RAX = guest_NRADDR
      4887D2 (xchgq %rdx,%rdx)   call-noredir *%RAX
      4887F6 (xchgq %rdi,%rdi)   IR injection

   Any other bytes following the 16-byte preamble are illegal and
   constitute a failure in instruction decoding.  This all assumes
   that the preamble will never occur except in specific code
   fragments designed for Valgrind to catch.

   No prefixes may precede a "Special" instruction.
*/

and the corrrespongding code
   /* Spot "Special" instructions (see comment at top of file). */
   {
      const UChar* code = guest_code + delta;
      /* Spot the 16-byte preamble:
         48C1C703   rolq $3,  %rdi
         48C1C70D   rolq $13, %rdi
         48C1C73D   rolq $61, %rdi
         48C1C733   rolq $51, %rdi
      */
      if (code[ 0] == 0x48 && code[ 1] == 0xC1 && code[ 2] == 0xC7 
                                               && code[ 3] == 0x03 &&
          code[ 4] == 0x48 && code[ 5] == 0xC1 && code[ 6] == 0xC7 
                                               && code[ 7] == 0x0D &&
          code[ 8] == 0x48 && code[ 9] == 0xC1 && code[10] == 0xC7 
                                               && code[11] == 0x3D &&
          code[12] == 0x48 && code[13] == 0xC1 && code[14] == 0xC7 
                                               && code[15] == 0x33) {
         /* Got a "Special" instruction preamble.  Which one is it? */
         if (code[16] == 0x48 && code[17] == 0x87 
                              && code[18] == 0xDB /* xchgq %rbx,%rbx */) {
            /* %RDX = client_request ( %RAX ) */
            DIP("%%rdx = client_request ( %%rax )\n");
            delta += 19;
            jmp_lit(&dres, Ijk_ClientReq, guest_RIP_bbstart+delta);
            vassert(dres.whatNext == Dis_StopHere);
            goto decode_success;
         }
         else


Just FYI, this check compiles to checking one byte at a time (https://godbolt.org/z/Pvbd5sP8s), which is quite a lot of code bloat.  The first check, for a REX.W prefix, will have a lot of false-positives, although the rol opcode is rare in real codebases.  I guess this has to work even if execution stops at a backwards jmp rel8 as the last 2 bytes of a page before an unmapped page, though.  Or even an int3 as the final byte of a page?  A longer instruction starting at the end of a page will need to fetch from the next page.

Anyway, memcmp(code, "\x48\xc1\xc7\x03", 4) != 0 can check the first 4 bytes with one cmp/jcc, very low chance of false-positives, so should improve branch-prediction.  But again, not safe if the guest RIP is in the last 3 bytes of a page before an unmapped page.  2-byte memcmp as the first check will be safe in real-world programs that doesn't use 1-byte trap instructions in the last byte of a page.  Of course this would be fine if you checked code & 4095 for being < (4096-4), but that's going in the opposite direction of keeping machine-code size small here :/

If this code runs for every guest instruction, it might branch-predict better to check code for not being right at the end of a page, then doing a 2-byte or 4-byte memcmp to start with, so everything except REX.W rol predicts the same way, and the near-end-of-page check probably mispredicts less than a check for 0x48 REX.W on its own.  (Otherwise fall back to checking 1 byte at a time.)  But this costs more static code size in valgrind than what you have now since you still need to handle the marker spanning a page.  And more source complexity.

We don't use libc. Our replacement for memcmp, VG_(memcmp) probably isn't the fastest. And we just don't have the resources for micro-optimizations like this. For the moment trying to keep things running and usability improvements are the main objectives.

You don't want libc memcmp, you only want compiler-builtin memcmp that expands inline for short constant lengths, especially power-of-2 lengths.  (Which you can still use as __builtin_memcmp under GCC and Clang even if you compile with -fno-builtin).  But yeah, I don't see an equally-safe way to write this that's as readable and maintainable (and portable), so it's fully reasonable not to change anything.
